# Where can I find data on past forecasts of planned aircraft production?

Tags: datasets, aircraft-production

Does anyone know of a database which would list the expected production rates for various aircraft, at the time those aircraft started production?

Finding *actual* production to date is easy, but I would be interested in what was the original *planned* production. I am not interested in current forecasts, I am interested in past forecasts that have been made before or at the start of production for the particular aircraft.

E.g. Cessna 152 was assumed by the manufacturer to be sold at the volume of XX aircraft per year, when the production plan was put into place.

Comment: I don't know of any consolidated database listing the forecast of deliveries and future of the market, but usually aircraft manufactures lists their forecasts in documents available for the public like [Airbus for the next 20 years](http://www.aircraft.airbus.com/market/global-market-forecast-2017-2036/) or [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/market/current-market-outlook-2017/) . This is a start.

Answer (score 3):

Yes both Airbus and Boeing deliver 20-year forecast for the complete market. For Airbus there is [a spreadsheet](http://www.aircraft.airbus.com/market/global-market-forecast-2017-2036/?eID=maglisting_push&tx_maglisting_pi1%5BdocID%5D=233939) which may function as your database.

IATA also publishes 20 year travel forecasts, [here is the latest](http://www.iata.org/pressroom/pr/Pages/2016-10-18-02.aspx). Airline travel is going to double over the next 20 years.

At he time of first production, forecasts for the aircraft are made based on market forecasts, plus the expected market share that the aircraft may achieve. Information that is of interest to the stakeholders of the company.

Comment: Right, I think I haven't made my question clear. I am not really interested in forecast at this moment in time, I am interested in forecasts for existing aircraft that have been done at the start of their production. The ultimate goal would be to make comparisons between the expectations vs reality retrospectively.